# NSUser default is not saving any value

Tags: ios, iphone, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to store userid coming from server to userDefaults which is a NSUserDefault object, but its always showing 0 for the value of userDefaults, I had tried using setObject method too but still its not working, and i have checked for informatioon coming from server its never a 0. value for user id is never 0 but still NSUserDefault is showin a 0 for it.

```
int userid=[[userdata objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];
[userDefaults setInteger:userid forKey:@"UserID "];
[userDefaults synchronize];
NSLog(@"UID: %d",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"UserID"]);
```

please help me thanks.

Comment: How do you initialize `userDefaults`? Did you try `[userDefaults integerForKey:@"UserID"]`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are saving using the key `@"UserId "` **note the space** and reading using the key `@"UserId"` **without an extra space**.

Comment: Thanks a ton David Ronnqvist

Answer (score 5):

As David Rönnqvist pointed out, you have a space in one of your keys but not in the other.

What I usually do is to #define all my user defaults keys in a file constants.h, and then use those constants instead of re-typing the string literal each time. This makes mistakes like yours impossible, and also makes it easier to keep track of the keys you are using.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this way to store and retrieve data..
for set the value..

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:10 forKey:@"USERID"];
```

for retrieve the value..

```
NSLog(@"%d",[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"USERID"]integerValue]);
```

good luck..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
int userid=[[userdata objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];

[userDefaults setInteger:userid forKey:@"UserID"];

[userDefaults synchronize];

NSLog(@"UID: %d",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"UserID"]);
```

Happy coding........